# Maxima in electric fields in various systems

Tags: electric-fields

In a charged ring the distance of R/root(2) from centre there is maximum electric field due to it. I know that mathematics provides a quite legitimate answer to it but I just cannot find a conceptual answer. Similarly in a system of two opposite unequal charges with a greater positive charge, the point beyond which field is 0 the field increases and a maxima occurs. This is the point where I am not able to answer it with  any concept. I just cannot understand what is special about that particular point . Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field on the axis of symmetry of a uniformly charged ring is zero at the center of the ring (the field from each segment of charge is balanced by the field from a similar charge on the opposite side.)  As you move away the plane of the ring, the resultant field increases for a while and then drops off with distance.
  A positive charge and a smaller negative charge define a line. If you start near the negative charge and move along the line away from both, the field from the negative charge will dominate until you reach a point where the the two fields are equal but opposite. Beyond that point the field from the positive charge will be stronger. After  passing the zero point the resultant field will increase for a  while and then drop off with distance.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘a positive and a smaller negative charge define a line’?

Comment: Any two points define a line.